# Flash Player Web Page Issue

Tags: firefox, flash

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. When I try to open the Adobe Flash Player download page, Firefox shows an error that it is unable to open the page. It opens other pages fine but no the above page. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using **Ubuntu 32bit** you don't install Adobe Flash Player the same way you do when using Windows. To install Flash player plugin for Firefox in Ubuntu you have to open Synaptic package manager, and type in the search field these keywords: **flash player**.

To open Synaptic, press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal window, and in that window type this code:

```
  sudo synaptic
```

Enter your password when prompted for it and wait for the application to load. Do not close the terminal window. If synaptic is not present on your system, you need to install it by running this code in the same terminal window:

```
  sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After you open Synaptic Package Manager, go to Settings - Repositories - Other Software and check the **Canonical Partners** and the **Independent** repos. Close the window for repositories and reload your software sources with the reload button from Synaptic menu.

Next you can type in the search field **flash player** as keyword and after getting the results look for and install the following packages: **adobe-flashplugin** and **adobe-flash-properties-gtk**. And you're done, you can use flash player in firefox.

If you run **Ubuntu 64bit**, a solution for installing Flash Player 64bit can be found [on this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMD64/FirefoxAndPlugins).